# Wrong Return Type/Scanner

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner, hashset

*emphasized text*I am currently trying to run this code (with two different files). One file is just a dictionary of words and the other is just a file with some text. When I run this code, my code outputs the entire text of the file that is provided in getIncorrectWords. I know this is wrong since there are errors that this SpellChecker should be picking up (and only the incorrect words should be printed out). I went back to make some changes to my constructor and I cannot seem to find the error in my code. Can anyone provide some input as to what could be going wrong with my program and provide some hints or advice for how to fix it? For reference I am making a SpellChecker which stores a "dictionary" -some defined words, in a HashSet. I am supposed to parse through another file and check which words in it are not defined in the dictionary and store those in a List. This is done n my getIncorrectWords method. Finally I am providing suggestions for what words could have been meant in my getSuggestions method. The suggestions are found by the following:

Add One Character - Try adding a character at every point in the string and see if that creates a valid word.

Remove One Character - Try removing one character from any position and see if that creates a valid word.

Exchange Adjacent Characters - Try swapping two consecutive characters at any position in the string and see if that creates a valid word.

Thank you for the time and input!

```
public class SpellChecker {
    private Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<>();

    public SpellChecker(String fileName) {
        dictionary = getDictionary(fileName);
    }

    public List<String> getIncorrectWords(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String word = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                if (!dictionary.contains(word)) {
                    words.add(word);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return words;
    }

    public static List<String> getSuggestions(String word){
    List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
                                       "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
                                       "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
                                       "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"); 
    List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(word); 
    for(int i = 0; i <= builder.length(); i++){
        for(String string: letters){
            StringBuilder suggestion = new StringBuilder(builder.toString());
            suggestion.insert(i, string); 
            if(dictionary.contains(suggestion.toString().toLowerCase())){
                suggestions.add(suggestion.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= builder.length()-2; i++){
        for(String string: letters){
            StringBuilder suggestion = new StringBuilder(builder.toString());
            char one = suggestion.charAt(i + 1);
            char two = suggestion.charAt(i);
            suggestion.replace(i, i + 1, String.valueOf(one));
            suggestion.replace(i+1, i + 2, String.valueOf(two));
            if(dictionary.contains(suggestion.toString().toLowerCase())){
                suggestions.add(suggestion.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= builder.length(); i++){
        for(String string: letters){
            StringBuilder suggestion = new StringBuilder(builder.toString());
            suggestion.replace(i, i + 1, "");
            if(dictionary.contains(suggestion.toString().toLowerCase())){
                suggestions.add(suggestion.toString());
            }
        }
   }
   return suggestions;
}

    public Set<String> getDictionary(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String word = input.nextLine().trim();
                dictionary.add(word.toLowerCase());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

This is my main class where I call the functions.

```
public class SpellCheckerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SpellChecker checker = new SpellChecker("words.txt");
        List<String> incorrectWords = checker.getIncorrectWords("test.txt");

        for (String word : incorrectWords) {
            List<String> suggestions = checker.getSuggestions(word);
            System.out.print(word + " - ");
            for (String suggestion : suggestions) {
                System.out.print(suggestion + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know how are you calling these functions. From the code you provided the description of the behavior is correct. `getIncorrectWords()` will return a list with unknown words.

Comment: @uli my mistake. I went back to add my main method.

Comment: Could you confirm that application printing all expected incorrect words (no more, no less), but suggested all words from dictionary?

Comment: @uli no. It actually prints out every word in the dictionary both the correct and incorrect words. It essentially copies the exact output in the "test.txt" file as opposed to just those words that are not defined in the "words.txt" file.

Comment: Is it the latest version of the code? It cannot be executed: missing return statement for `getSuggestions()`. I added it and executed on words: boom, test: boom, fail. it printed `fail -`. As expected, no issues. may be you could provide an example of data that fails for you.

Comment: @uli the code I was running had the return statement. I think I just copied it wrong into here. https://github.com/amt2252/TextFiles I have uploaded the files into GitHub. The words.txt files is the dictionary and the test.txt file is the file with the misspelled words. I really appreciate your help!